# How to get class of the element in stimulus.js

Tags: javascript, slim, stimulusjs

I want to toggle elements and I need a class names for that.
How can I get a class name of the nested element in stimulus.js and change it?
F.I, I need to toggle the "ul" element that is initially hidden.

```
div data-controller="my_controller"
  a data-action="click->my_controller#toggle_my_elements"
    | Click
  ul.is-hidden id="my-id" data-target="my_controller.mytext"
    li
      | Text to be toggled.
```

and in stimulus controller I have:

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus'

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["mytext"]
  toggle_my_elements(){
    console.log("debuggin")  //Ok
    const class_name = this.mytextTarget.className
  }
}
```

I tried to call a js function `className` but it seems js functions don't work in the way they used to.
I just can't figure out how to get it.

Answer (score 5):

As StimulusJS *target* is a *HTML element*, you can use its `classList` property

```js
this.mytextTarget.classList.remove('is-hidden')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to get the `ul` class:

```
static targets = [ "mytext" ]

connect() {
  this.mytextClass = this.data.get("class") || "is-hidden"
}
```

Then use the following action descriptor to toggle your `ul` element

```
toggle(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  this.mytextTargets.forEach(target => {
    target.classList.toggle(this.mytextClass)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `element[:class]`?
That's how I access the class of the html element from a Stimulus Reflex in ruby since `element.class` returns the class of the element (a StimulusReflex::Element) instead of the "btn btn-primary" String I was expecting.